# user defined gaussian kernel

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I was wondering if anyone could look at this code. I'm trying to do a 3x3 gaussian kernel without using any matlab built-in functions. (Yes I am aware of all the built in functions of gaussian and convolution ie fspecial)
the result gives me a white image instead. not sure what's the problem with it.

```
clc;

close all;

clear all;

img=imread('image.jpg');

figure,imshow(img);

img2=zeros(size(img)+2);

newImg=zeros(size(img));
for rgb=1:3

        for x=1:size(img,1)

            for y=1:size(img,2)

                img2(x+1,y+1,rgb)=img(x,y,rgb);

            end
        end
end
    for i= 1:size(img2,1)-2

        for j=1:size(img2,2)-2

            window=zeros(9,1);

            inc=1;

            for x=1:3

                for y=1:3

                    window(inc)=img2(i+x-1,j+y-1,rgb);

                    inc=inc+1;

                end

            end
              kernel=[1;2;1;2;4;2;1;2;1];

%             kernel=[0;1;0;1;-4;1;0;1;0];

            med=window.*kernel;

            disp(med);

            med=sum(med);

            med=floor(med);

            newImg(i,j,:)=med;

        end

    end

newImg=uint8(newImg);

figure,imshow(newImg);
```

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of result are you getting? Compiler error, bad data, no data?

Comment: The result is as stated - I got a white block image instead of a blurred/smoothed image.

Comment: I don't work with matplab, but are you sure it's not the issue of datatypes ? image could easily be 8bit integer so it would easily overflow in the process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should normalize the `kernel`. I mean, devide each element by the sum of their value (16), to make their sum equal to 1:

```
kernel=[1;2;1;2;4;2;1;2;1]/16;
```

Comment: I tested this solution and it works for me. It's important that jpg compression will make the image blurred, so it's better to try your code on an uncompressed image (e.g. uncompressed jpg or bmp).

Comment: It worked thank you. I've been trying to make that the function takes an input image and a different size kernel like for example instead of pre-defined 3x3 kernel as above, it could instead take 5x5 or 7x7. and then the user could input the type of kernel/filter they want(Depending on the intended effect). I can't seem to put my head around it. i'm quite new to matlab.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it worked :) Please accept my answer. You could ask a new question about the problem of kernels of different size.